# How to execute a piece of code only after all threads are done

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I have a logging code which needs to be executed after all `Threads`s are executed.

```
Thread t1 = new MyThread();
Thread t2 = new MyThread();
t1.run();
t2.run();

doLogging();
```

Is there any way to execute `doLogging()` only after both threads are done with their processing. Now that `doLogging()` is called as soon as t1 and t2 are started.

Comment: It should be pointed out that since you are calling run instead of start you're already getting the desired behavior.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just [`join()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) all threads before your `doLogging()` call:

```
t1.join();
t2.join();

// the following line will be executed when both threads are done
doLogging();
```

Note that the order of `join()` calls doesn't matter if you want to wait for all of your threads.

Comment: Note that if you're using Java 1.5 or later the new java.util.concurrent should be preferred over low-level thread programming (see Gregory Mostizky's answer).

Comment: @Jim: with Java 1.5 or later I wouldn't even use a CountDownLatch for such a thing, but a simple Executor.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the join() solution there is also something called CountDownLatch in the java.util.concurrent library. It allows you to initialize it to a certain number and then wait until it was hit the specified number of times.

Simple example:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
for(int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_THREADS;i++)
   new Thread(myCode).start();

latch.await();
```

The latch must be explicitly hit by the worker threads for this to work though:

```
latch.countDown()
```

Comment: +1 for java.util.concurrent.  This new feature makes most low-level thread programming in Java unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you create threads using a thread pool, then you may use `awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` method. Once time up, it will return true if all threads are finished, otherwise return false.

```
if(awaitTermination(timeout, unit)){
    //write your code here
}
```

**However**, since you need to estimate a timeout first, it's not as flexible as CountDownLatch. This method is usually used together with `shutdown()` to double-check if all threads are shut down successfully given a waiting time.